# Migrating ghcup from C:\ to D:\

Tags: haskell, ghcup

I'm trying to migrate GHCUP from my C:\ drive to my D:\ drive. I have adjusted my environment variables for PATH and GHCUP_INSTALL_BASE_PREFIX to show the new drive. What else do I need to change so my IDE can find the runhaskell command. My IDE can find the files within D:\ drive just fine. I just can't figure out how to get it to run through the D:\ address instead of the C:\ address which I have removed. I'm using VS Code, though I don't think it's a VS CODE issue.

PS C:\Users\blain\OneDrive\Desktop\VS_CODE> runhaskell "c:\Users\blain\OneDrive\Desktop\VS_CODE\Haskell\Hello_World.hs"

Could not create process with command 'C:\ghcup\ghc\8.10.7\bin\runhaskell.exe c:\Users\blain\OneDrive\Desktop\VS_CODE\Haskell\Hello_World.hs'.

This is the exact issue. I need the command to become:

D:\ghcup\ghc\8.10.7\bin\runhaskell.exe c:\Users\blain\OneDrive\Desktop\VS_CODE\Haskell\Hello_World.hs'.

my environment variables

variable: GHCUP_INSTALL_BASE_PREFIX

value: D:\ghcup

Path:

D:\ghcup\bin

In conclusion, I'm trying to migrate ghcup from C:\ to D:, what do I need to do to get my IDE to recognize the new home of ghcup to be D:\ and not C:\ so I can use the runhaskell command?
[Snip of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQ7QO.jpg)

Comment: Have you looked into settings of the Haskell VS Code extensions? It may have a wrong path recorded. Otherwise, first confirm that you can run GHC (e.g. `ghc --version`) in the terminal.

Comment: Open vscode settings and search for `Haskell: Ghcup Executable Path`. Try by modifiying it to `D:\...`. You have to point to the `.exe` file, normally should be in some path like `D:\ghcup\ghcup.exe` but I am not a windows user so be chack it first in your system